# Sending a DataTable's content in an html email, what is the preferred way to generate HTML from a DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html, datatable

Sending a DataTable's content in an html email, what is the preferred way to generate HTML from a DataTable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind to GridView or DataGrid and use the RenderControl method.

http://blogs.x2line.com/al/articles/859.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could either :

- manually generate an HTML table by looping through the table data
- serialize the `DataTable` to XML (`WriteXml` method), and perform an XSL transform on the XML to generate HTML